# Почему не отображается виджет label?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlabel, qmainwindow

Есть два файла: **`MainGui.py`** и **`Interface.py`**. 
Первый отвечает за главное окно и сопутствующие методы, 
второй за виджеты, которые будут на этом окне расположены.

**MainGui.py**:

```
import sys
from Interface import UI_setup


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QStyleFactory, QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(900, 550)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #24232d;")

        self.design = UI_setup()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.design)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    application = MainWindow()
    application.setWindowTitle("Title")
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Interface.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, \
    QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout


class UI_setup(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setStyleSheet("color: #fff;")
        label.setMinimumSize(170, 25)

        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(box)
```

Не могу понять, почему `label` не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное окно обеспечивает основу для создания пользовательского интерфейса приложения. Qt имеет `QMainWindow` и связанные с ним классы для управления главным окном. 
**`QMainWindow` имеет собственный макет**, в который вы можете добавлять QToolBar, QDockWidgets, QMenuBar и QStatusBar. 
Макет имеет центральную область, которая может быть занята любым виджетом.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

**q1380378_mainGui.py**

```
import sys
from q1380378_interface import UI_setup


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QStyleFactory, QWidget, QApplication, 
    QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(900, 550)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #24232d;")

        self.design = UI_setup()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                         # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)              # +++

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)               # +++ self.centralWidget
        layout.addWidget(self.design)

# -        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    application = MainWindow()
    application.setWindowTitle("Title")
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1380378_interface.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, \
    QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout


class UI_setup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QLabel('Hello World')
        label.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #ccffbd; color: #f00; font-size: 20px;")
        label.setMinimumSize(170, 25)

        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(box)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: @pythoncoder пожалуйста.